# Runtimeerror: cannot get window extent w/o renderer with seaborn

Tags: macos, matplotlib, seaborn

So I'm trying to get some stuff running with seaborn (specifically this [example](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/structured_heatmap.html))

However when I run on normal `ipython` I get the runtime error listed in the title.  It seems like a backend issue but I don't experience this with any other plotting utilities.  Even stranger, if I run in the `ipython notebook` I no longer experience that error.  I can certainly work with in the notebook for now and avoid problems but it's concerning that this happens in a terminal.

Comment: Do you happen to be on a mac?

Comment: @cel I do!  Is there a good fix for it?

Comment: Hmh, I can reproduce it on my mac. It seems to be caused only by the `MacOSX` backend. Switching to other backends via `mpl.use()` seems to be a workaround.

Comment: @cel worked for me as too, do you have a specific backend that you think works well?  Either way if you write that up as a response you'll get the check.  Thanks!

Comment: well, it's more a workaround than an answer, so I don't want to post it as an answer. I am using the notebook for all my plotting, so I haven't run into this issue yet. But I think it would make sense understanding and fixing it. I would suggest retagging with `osx`, and `matplotlib` and removing the ipython tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `MacOSX` backend. It is tracked at `matplotlib`'s issue tracker, but a fix apparently needs major rewriting and is not finished yet. (I guess related to this [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2654)).

In the meantime switching the plotting backend is a workaround.

This can be done e.g. via command line by starting ipython with

```
ipython --matplotlib <your-favorite-backend>
```

Choosing an invalid backend (`ipython --matplotlib ??`) will print all available backends.

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | The 'matplotlib' trait of a TerminalIPythonApp instance must be any of ['auto', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'inline', 'nbagg', 'osx', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'tk', 'wx'] or None, but a value of '??' <class 'str'> was specified.
```

Comment: Just for future proofing, using `--matplotlib` on the commandline is deprecated and going away in IPython 3, but the same thing can be achieved by with the `%matplotlib` magic.

Comment: @mwaskom, oh I didn't know that. Do you have a link for that? It seems that `--pylab` already got deprecated, so you are probably right. However I could not find a link for the deprecation of `--matplotlib`