# Seaborn matplotlib: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer (RuntimeError)

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a *seaborn* *clustermap* (it doesn't work with the *heatmap* too) with the following, no NaNs admitted:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotClusterMap():
    a = pd.DataFrame(np.matrix('1 2; 3 4'))
    print a
    fig = plt.figure()
    sns.clustermap(a)
    plt.show()
```

`a` is well formed:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 72, in main
    heatmapPlotter.plotClusterMap()
  File "/Users/username/code.py", line 12, in plotClusterMap
    sns.clustermap(a)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py", line 895, in clustermap
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py", line 813, in plot
    self.plot_matrix(colorbar_kws, mask, **kws)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py", line 803, in plot_matrix
    cbar_kws=colorbar_kws, mask=mask, **kws)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py", line 292, in heatmap
    plotter.plot(ax, cbar_ax, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py", line 177, in plot
    if axis_ticklabels_overlap(xtl):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py", line 374, in axis_ticklabels_overlap
    bboxes = [l.get_window_extent() for l in labels]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 796, in get_window_extent
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer
```

- Mac OSX: <del>10.9</del> 10.10.3 (*edit*)
- Seaborn: 0.5.1
- Matplotlib: 1.3.1 (just downgraded from 1.4)
- Numpy: 1.8.0
- Python: 2.7.9

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868865/runtimeerror-cannot-get-window-extent-w-o-renderer-with-seaborn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.5, python 2.7.9, matplotlib 1.4.3, and seaborn 0.5.1.  I was able to reproduce the error.

By default I am using the `macosx` backend for matplotlib.  Your code works if I change the backend to `qt4agg` (requires PyQt4), `tkagg` or `webagg`.  Here's the script that worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt4agg')  # Can also use 'tkagg' or 'webagg'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


def plotClusterMap():
    a = pd.DataFrame(np.matrix('1 2; 3 4'))
    print a
    # fig = plt.figure()
    sns.clustermap(a)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plotClusterMap()
```

Note that I commented out `fig = plt.figure()`.  `clustermap` appears to create its own figure.

Comment: this works fine! I used _tkagg_ since _qt4agg_ require a longer installation

Comment: @EnricoRotundo How do you install tkagg/webagg?

Comment: It was a while ago don't really remember. I think it comes with matplotlib by default on macOS. If not, it seems that installing matplotlib from source will install it.